# Try to do Forgot Password with AJAX and getin "Internal Server Error [500]"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services

So im trying to do Forgot password method that user enter his email with JavaScript prompt alert and send it to WebService

I think that my problem is in the Jquery side,because when i run the WebService.asmx with "Invoke" method the email sent succsusfully!
but when i try to run index.html on chrome it gives me "Internal Server Error [500]."

so..
here the Jquery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
wireEventsLoginPage();
```

});

```
function wireEventsLoginPage() {
$('#forgetPassword').unbind('click').click(function () {
    var email = window.prompt("Write Your Email Here", "");
    $.ajax({
        url: WebServiceURL + "/ForgotPassword",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST", //use only POST!
        data: JSON.stringify(email),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            alert(formatErrorMessage(jqXHR, exception));
        },
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var res = data.d;
            if (res == 'Email Sent') {
                alert("Password Sent!");
            }
            else {
                alert("Couldnt recovery password");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

}

And this is the server side:

```
 [WebMethod]
public string ForgotPassword(string emailPar)
{
    string output = "ERROR USER!";
    try
    {
        comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM FOOTUSERTB WHERE EMAIL= '" + emailPar + "'";
        comm.Connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
            {
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("testfootapp@gmail.com", "*******"),
                EnableSsl = true
            };
            client.Send("testfootapp@gmail.com", reader["EMAIL"].ToString(), "Your Password Recovery", "Your password is: " + reader["PASSWORD"]);
            output = "Email Sent";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        output = ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        comm.Connection.Close();
    }
    JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return json.Serialize(output);
}
```

I hope that will find my problem 
and many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

it could be just a routing problem regarding to the fact that your server code run successfully.

> Internal Server Error usually means that your program cannot access the URL you asked for. There is different reasons for it.

Are you sure your Web service is accessible at the address in the "WebServiceURL" variable ?

Comment: i have a JavaScript file that keep all the globals variabls like "WebServiceURL" and is not declared in the JavaScript file that i have the AJAX call from above

Comment: Did you try other calls in that case ? What I tried to say is that it could be a problem of routing or networking (port exposure, dns ...)